# Any free distance APIs out there?

Tags: api, maps

I am looking for an alternative to the Google Maps Distance calculator API.  I have seen a number of options, and all seem to require payment.

I am not even sure I would be running this API very often (maybe less than 40,000 queries a month).

The closest thing I could see to "free" was Bing Maps version, but that required an Azure account, and I'm not dealing with that multi-headed monster again.

Does anyone know of a free, or relatively inexpensive version?